# Rails routes in production are looking for param: id. How do I tell it to use :order_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, path, routes

I recently connected a remote DB to the **production** version of my site.  However, now my routes do not work.

In my Heroku logs, my app is looking for `Parameters: {"id"=>"edit"}.`

**But there is not an :id parameter in my database.** The only index specified is **order_id**.

How can I edit **routes.db** so that the **order_id** is used in my paths?  And is this even necessary or is there something else I should look at?

**List of columns in local db:**

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > Order.column_names
 => ["order_id", "product_status", "img_reference", "img_source", "user_email", "user_name", "user_address", "user_city", "user_zipcode", "user_state", "product_size", "product_type", "payment_id", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at"]
```

**List of columns in remote db:**

```
irb(main):001:0> Order.column_names
=> ["order_id", "order_date", "product_status", "img_reference", "img_source", "user_email", "user_name", "user_address", "user_city", "user_zipcode", "user_state", "product_size", "product_type", "uservendor_id", "paypal_confirmation"]
```

**Again, my routes seem to work just fine in my development version.**

The only difference I can think of is there's a few extra columns in my remote db which I don't think should effect the routes.

This is the error I get in my Heroku logs:

```
2014-05-08T15:28:55.461192+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/orders//edit" for 76.102.227.168 at 2014-05-08 15:28:55 +0000
2014-05-08T15:28:55.465958+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
2014-05-08T15:28:55.461180+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/orders//edit" for 76.102.227.168 at 2014-05-08 15:28:55 +0000
2014-05-08T15:28:55.465965+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
2014-05-08T15:28:55.465988+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"edit"}
2014-05-08T15:28:55.466009+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"edit"}
2014-05-08T15:28:55.469914+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms
2014-05-08T15:28:55.469922+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470930+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470933+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order without an ID):
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470935+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:69:in `set_order'
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470938+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470937+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470943+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470945+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order without an ID):
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470946+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:69:in `set_order'
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470948+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-08T15:28:55.470949+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: In model, try `self.primary_key = :order_id`, it may work.

Comment: Ok, adding an answer for the record, would be glad if you accept it

Answer (score 0):

So, in ActiveRecord if you have a custom primary key you need to specify it in the model

```
class Order
  self.primary_key = :order_id
```

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions